# Unable to get values of dynamically created controls c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, dynamic-controls

I have created dynamic controls on button click and I'm not able to retrieve values of dynamically created controls. I am getting values of dynamic controls inside a panel.

`pnlDepartment` is the Panel ID.

```
protected void btnValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strDDLValue = string.Empty;
    foreach (DropDownList ddl in pnlDepartment.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>())
    {
        strDDLValue = ddlName.SelectedItem.Text + "," + ddlLocation.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
}
```

The `strDDLValue` has only first dropdown values and when it loops for the second time it still takes the first dropdown values and unable to get dynamic control values.

Please correct me if I'm making a mistake somewhere.

Updated code:

```
 string strDDLValue = string.Empty;
            foreach (DropDownList ddl in pnlDepartment.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>())
            {
                strDDLValue = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
            }
```

Comment: how do you add the dynamic controls to `pnlDepartment`

Comment: You haven't used the `ddl` variable which is declared in your `foreach`.

Comment: That's because you're using static objects (`ddlName` and `ddlLocation`) instead of the `ddl` DropDownList from your `foreach` loop.

Comment: You need to use the FindChild Method. Take a look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used the dll variable. If the foreach loop in the pnlDeportment only contains the name. You will have to use this method.

```
protected void btnValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
    string strDDLValue = string.Empty;
    foreach (DropDownList ddl in pnlDepartment.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>())
    {
        strDDLValue = ddl.SelectedItem.Text
    }
}
```

Other wise you must create two list that adds the dropdown for the name and one for the location.

init your lists at the init of your page.

```
List<DropDownList> ddlNames;
List<DropDownList> ddlLocations;

protected void btnValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{ 
     if (dllNames.Count() == ddlLocations.Count())
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < ddlNames.Count(); i++)
         {
              strDDLValue = string.Format("{0},{1}", 
               ddlNames[i].SelectedItem.Text,
               ddlLocations[i].SelectedItem.Text );
         }
     }
}
```

Make sure you get the list of controls that you need by:

```
 int i = 0;
foreach (DropDownList ddl in pnlDepartment.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>())
{
    i++;
    ddl.SelectedItem.Text = string.Format("Found:{0}",i);
}
```

Comment: I'm creating two dynamic dropdown controls inside a panel and I'm unable to get values of dynamically created control values. Updated post with the code.

Comment: I have updated my anser, Please make sure that u get the list that u want.